# Custom Chrome Search Engine for site with frames does not work

Tags: google-chrome, search-engines

Usually when I search something on a site, Google Chrome automatically adds it to Preferences -> Basics -> Search -> Manage Search Engines -> Other search engines.

However, even though I searched things [here](http://tdkterim.gov.tr/bts/) tons of times, that one isn't available in that "other search engines" section. How do I add it there manually?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95653

> ## Manage search engine options
>
> Google Chrome automatically saves a list of the search engines you've come across while browsing the web. For example, if you visit http://www.youtube.com, the browser automatically detects and adds the YouTube search engine to the list of search engines that you can access from the address bar.
>
> To manually add, edit, or remove search engines from the browser, follow the steps below. These steps apply to Google Chrome in Windows, Mac, Linux, and Chrome OS.
>
> - Click the wrench icon  on the browser toolbar.
> - Select Options (Preferences on Mac and Linux; Settings on Chrome OS).
> - Click the Basics tab.
> - Click Manage search engines in the "Search" section.
>
> Add a search engine: Scroll to the bottom of the dialog and fill out the following fields:
>
> > - Add a new search engine: Enter a nickname for the search engine.
> > - Keyword: Enter the text shortcut you want to use for the search engine. Use the keyword to do keyword searches.
> > - URL: Enter the web address for the search engine.

Comment: link only answers are *discouraged* here on SU, please expand your answer.

Comment: I cannot see the word I'm searching for in the URL (to replace with %s), hence I cannot apply that solution.

Comment: The website you link to uses frames. When you search the frame URL changes to tdkterim.gov.tr/bts/arama/?kategori=verilst&kelime=THISISATEST&ayn=tam however if you visit the frame outside of the site the contents do not load.

Comment: *> I cannot see the word I'm searching for in the URL (to replace with %s), hence I cannot apply that solution.* If you do a search then right-click in the resulting page and select *View frame source*, you can see the URL. For example: `view-source:http://tdkterim.gov.tr/bts/arama/?kategori=verilst&kelime=TEST_QUERY&ayn=tam` Unfortunately, if you try navigating to [that URL](http://tdkterim.gov.tr/bts/arama/?kategori=verilst&kelime=TEST_QUERY&ayn=tam), it gives you a blank (literally empty, as in 0-bytes) page. Like todda said, it seems to be a problem with the frames.